# What does "Wbem" and "SWbem" mean in the WMI Scripting API?

Tags: windows, wmi, nomenclature

In the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) Scripting API, [constant names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393257%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) start with "Wbem", and [object names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) start with "SWbem". What do these abbreviations stand for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Web-Based Enterprise Management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-Based_Enterprise_Management) and I believe the S means Scripting...

Some other terms:

- WMI=Windows Management Instrumentation
- CIM=Common Information Model
- DMTF=Distributed Management Task Force